# Pantheon files does not open in Freya

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I put bellow the output when I run the command `pantheon-files` on shell.
Does anybody have any idea about this problem?

```
bnascimento@Vostro-3450:~$ pantheon-files
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 14:58:17.276886] Application.vala:155: Files version: 0.2.4
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 14:58:17.276977] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.19.0-43-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 14:58:17.281861] Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-b5TYPphJU9: Connection refused
org.gtk.vfs.MountTracker.listMountableInfo call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gtk.vfs.Daemon was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 14:58:17.313567] Application.vala:85: Report any issues/bugs you might find to http://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 14:58:17.319396] [Gtk] Attempting to read the recently used resources file at `/home/bnascimento/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Falha ao abrir arquivo "/home/bnascimento/.local/share/recently-used.xbel": Permission denied.
invoking IsSupported() failed for remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor:: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
invoking IsSupported() failed for remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor:: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
invoking IsSupported() failed for remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.Private.MTPVolumeMonitor:: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gtk.Private.MTPVolumeMonitor was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
Segmentation fault (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Comment: Have already taken a look at the [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files) or opened a new report? I'm inclined to close this question as I doubt there is a simple answer, but we can wait a bit for helpful answers.

Comment: I didn't find anything at the bug tracker. Some people talk about this problem in foruns. But no solution is given.

Comment: Well one of the errors is that you don't have permissions to modify things in your own home directory. Have you recently installed anything from a 3rd party source or copied any Terminal commands from the internet? Can you give us details about anything you did before this error occurred?

Comment: This question is very dificult. I dont have a idea about what occurred. I can answer about what happens now. But I didn't do any drastic change in the OS. I installed and uninstalled dropbox. I do not think the problem is related to it.

Comment: I found similar problem this post: [link] (http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/pantheon-files-will-not-open-in-freya-after-updating?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

It may be trying to restore tabs for locations that are invalid for some reason.  Try resetting the restored tabs to default by using dconf-editor - the key is org.pantheon.files.preferences tab-info-list.